# Stimulus js controller

Tags: stimulusjs

How do I call a stimulus controller function on page load?
Here is my function in stimulus controller:

```js
hide(event)
{
    $(this.testTargets[0].tpggle(event.currentTarget.checked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  connect() {
    this.[call action function name on target you want to set]   
  }
```

Can't tell what that name is by what you've given, but the connect function will call on load.

**EDIT after comment**

Okay, since I do not know what your html or your stimulus controller looks like. I'm going to guess.

I see *checkbox* on one line so I'm going to assume you have a checkbox that you want to check on page load. I'll assume your html looks something like this:

```html
<div data-controller="test">
  <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl">Test#index</h1>
  <p>Find me in app/views/test/index.html.erb</p>
  <%- arr = %w{one two three four five} %>
  <%- arr.each do |t| %>
    <%= check_box_tag t,'0',false ,data:{test_target:"checkbox"}%>
    <label><%= t %></label>
  <%- end %>
</div>
```

Just a page with 5 checkboxes that are targets.

To check the first one, its just:

```js
// file test_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "checkbox"]

  connect() {
    this.checkboxTargets[0].checked = true
  }

}
```

But I'll also assume you are going to do something else with the checkboxes. Maybe hide/show an element. I have no idea what you are going to do, but if you did want to hide/show element on the page it would be something like this and you have a class *hidden* that we are going to toggle:

```html
<div data-controller="test">
  <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl">Test#index</h1>
  <p>Find me in app/views/test/index.html.erb</p>
  <%- arr = %w{one two three four five} %>
  <%- arr.each do |t| %>
    <%= check_box_tag t,'0',false ,data:{test_target:"checkbox",
      action:"test#doSomething"}%>
    <label><%= t %></label>
  <%- end %>
  <div class="hidden" data-test-target="display">
    <span>Display one</span>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" data-test-target="display">
    <span>Display two</span>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" data-test-target="display">
    <span>Display three</span>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" data-test-target="display">
    <span>Display four</span>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" data-test-target="display">
    <span>Display five</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the expanded controller:

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "checkbox","display"]

  connect() {
    this.checkboxTargets[0].checked = true
    this.displayTargets[0].classList.remove('hidden')
  }

  doSomething(){
    var idx = this.checkboxTargets.indexOf(event.target)
    this.displayTargets[idx].classList.toggle('hidden')
  }
}
```

Hope this gets you started. It takes a little time to get the hang of stimulus terminology.

Comment: I trythis,connect(){  this.actionTargets.hide(event).testTarges}, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out my dude! Stimulus is great because it really relieves the pains that come w state management

in terminal:

```
$ rails g stimulus checkbox && rails g stimulus multiple_checkboxes
```

in app/javascript/controllers/checkbox_controller.js

```
// app/javascript/controllers/checkbox_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="checkbox"
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    toggled: Boolean // Defaults to false
  }

  static targets = [ "checkbox" ]

  // Lifecycle Callbacks
  // https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/lifecycle-callbacks#methods
  
  // initialize(){
  //   console.log("checkbox_controller initialized")          //  Once, when the controller is first instantiated
  // }
  // 
  // connect() {
  //   console.log("checkbox_controller connected")            // Anytime the controller is connected to the DOM
  // }
  // 
  // disconnect(){
  //   console.log("checkbox_controller disconnected")         // Anytime the controller is disconnected from the DOM
  // }
  // 
  // checkboxTargetConnected(element) {
  //   console.log("checkbox_controller target connected")     // Anytime a target is connected to the DOM
  // }
  // 
  // checkboxTargetDisconnected(element) {
  //   console.log("checkbox_controller target disconnected")  // Anytime a target is disconnected from the DOM
  // }

  changeToggleValue(element){
    this.toggledValue = !this.toggledValue
  }

  toggledValueChanged(value, previousValue) {
    if (previousValue != undefined ) {
      console.warn('toggledValueChanged')
      console.log('previousValue')
      console.log(previousValue)
      console.log('value')
      console.log(value)
    }
  }

}
```

in app/javascript/controllers/multiple_checkboxes_controller.js

```
// app/javascript/controllers/multiple_checkboxes_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="multiple-checkboxes"
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    toggled: Boolean
  }

  static targets = [ "checkbox" ]

  checkboxTargetConnected(element) {
    console.log('multiple-checkboxes checkboxTargetConnected')
  }

  changeToggleValue(){
    console.log('changeToggleValue')
    this.toggledValue = !this.toggledValue
    this.checkboxTargets.forEach(targ => targ.checked = this.toggledValue)
    this.anotherFunction()
  }

  selectAll(){
    console.log('selectAll:')
    if (this.toggledValue != true) {
      this.toggledValue = true
      this.checkboxTargets.forEach(targ => targ.checked = true)
      this.functionYouWantToInvokeOnSelectAll()
    } else {
      console.log('nothing to do! All targets are selected')
    }
  }

  functionYouWantToInvokeOnSelectAll(){
    console.log('The more the merrier')
  }

  unselectAll(){
    console.log('unselectAll:')
    if (this.toggledValue != false) {
      this.toggledValue = false
      this.checkboxTargets.forEach(targ => targ.checked = false)
      this.functionYouWantToInvokeOnUnselectAll()
    } else {
      console.log('nothing to do! No targets are selected' )
    }
  }

  functionYouWantToInvokeOnUnselectAll(){
    console.log('Less is more')
  }

  anotherFunction(){
    console.log('yezzzzirr')
  }

  toggledValueChanged(value, previousValue) {
    if (previousValue != undefined ) {
      console.warn('toggledValueChanged')
      console.log('previousValue')
      console.log(previousValue)
      console.log('value')
      console.log(value)
    }
  }

}
```

And finally this in your view:

```
<!-- 
Paste this in the head tag that lives in application.html.erb if you dont already have Tailwind installed 

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
-->

<div data-controller="checkbox" class="my-5">
  <span class="text-3xl"> checkbox </span>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" data-checkbox-target="checkbox" data-action="checkbox#changeToggleValue">
  <label for=""> w/e </label>
</div>

<div data-controller="multiple-checkboxes" class="my-5">
  <span class="text-3xl"> checkboxezzzz </span>
  <br>
  <div class="my-3 flex space-x-3">
    <button
     type="button"
     data-action="multiple-checkboxes#changeToggleValue"
     class="inline-flex items-center rounded border border-transparent bg-blue-100 px-2.5 py-1.5 text-xs font-medium text-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-offset-2">
      Toggle
    </button>
    <button
     type="button"
     data-action="multiple-checkboxes#selectAll"
     class="inline-flex items-center rounded border border-transparent bg-blue-100 px-2.5 py-1.5 text-xs font-medium text-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-offset-2">
      Select All
    </button>
    <button
     type="button"
     data-action="multiple-checkboxes#unselectAll"
     class="inline-flex items-center rounded border border-transparent bg-blue-100 px-2.5 py-1.5 text-xs font-medium text-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-offset-2">
      Unselect All
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="space-y-3">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-multiple-checkboxes-target="checkbox">
      <label for=""> w/e </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-multiple-checkboxes-target="checkbox">
      <label for=""> w/e </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-multiple-checkboxes-target="checkbox">
      <label for=""> w/e </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-multiple-checkboxes-target="checkbox">
      <label for=""> w/e </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-multiple-checkboxes-target="checkbox">
      <label for=""> w/e </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-multiple-checkboxes-target="checkbox">
      <label for=""> w/e </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-multiple-checkboxes-target="checkbox">
      <label for=""> w/e </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Good luck!